# I some how lost my vim in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim, reinstall

After messing stuff up trying to install/uninstall some plugins I hosed up vim completey. Running ubuntu server (no gui) how can I get back vim to the way it was originally installed with ubuntu (including any links).

$> sudo dpkg --get-selections
...
uuid-runtime                                    install
vim-common                                      deinstall
vim-runtime                                     deinstall
vim-tiny                                        deinstall
vsftpd                                          install
...

Hoping there's a way to just install those (and anything else that might be missing) 
Things that didn't work:
$> apt-get install vim-full

$> dpkg --get-selections > selections
$> dpkg --set-selections < selections
$> aptitude reinstall '~pstandard'
(after which I still see)
...
uuid-runtime                                    install
vim-common                                      deinstall
vim-runtime                                     deinstall
vim-tiny                                        deinstall
vsftpd                                          install
...

After that I still see just
a049212@ubuntu-rails:~$ sudo find / -type f -iname '*vim*'
/usr/share/gettext/styles/po-vim.css
/usr/share/man/man5/apparmor.vim.5.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-common_2%3a7.2.245-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim_2%3a7.2.245-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a7.2.245-2ubuntu2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-tiny_2%3a7.2.245-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-common.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-tiny.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-common.list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things I would try:

`aptitude reinstall vim`

If that doesn't work:

`aptitude install vim-tiny ; aptitude purge vim ; aptitude install vim`

Comment: +1 for using aptitude instead of apt-get

Comment: 1st didn't work. The 2nd led to the solution for me. I couldn't run the 2nd as it was. I kept getting "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock". When I seperated the 3 commands it worked. Here's my solution.
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo aptitude install vim-tiny
sudo aptitude purge vim
sudo aptitude install vim

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sorry about the single-line thing.  I habitually violate the Ubuntu guidelines and type "sudo su" before doing multi-step processes that require root.

Comment: @P.Langeberg: "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock" means that another instance of aptitude, apt-get or dpkg is already running.Removing it helps, but you should first check that there's really no ohter aptitude etc. running.